# Can a created report automatically assign a subscription based on a specific filter within the report?

Tags: reporting, automation, filters, subscriber

Can a created report automatically assign a subscription based on a specific filter within the report?
For example, a report based on a ticketing system with case owners of the ticket(s) (which would update daily), can the owner of the ticket who appears under the report be sent the email? This would be based on users who have an active SF account with an email address. Currently the only way I can adjust this, is to manually add users to the subscription based on manual review of the open tickets.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a custom solution for this. Set up a record triggered flow on Case to add the Case owner to a public group whenever the case meets the report filter condition.
Then add this public group as a recipient for report subscription. This should automate the manual addition of users.